# How to inject field interface into an object

Tags: delphi, dependency-injection, spring4d

I want to inject an interface into an object but I can't find the problem of the attribute [Inject]

What's working.

```
unit uStorage;

interface

uses
  uStorageInterface;

type
  TStorageService = class (TInterfacedObject, IStorageService)
  private
    FPath: String;
    procedure SetPath(const Value: String);
    function GetPath: String;
   public
     property Path: String read GetPath write SetPath;
   end;

implementation

{ TStorageService }

function TStorageService.GetPath: String;
begin
  Result:= FPath;
end;

procedure TStorageService.SetPath(const Value: String);
begin
  FPath := Value;
end;
```

---

```
unit uStorageInterface;

interface

type
   IStorageService = interface
     ['{F1B4C339-BE8E-4182-A191-95266160FA6E}']
     procedure SetPath(const Value: String);
     function GetPath: String;
     property Path: String read GetPath write SetPath;
   end;

   IStorageObject = interface
     ['{7B97B659-EDF3-4892-AFAB-985487660372}']
   end;

implementation

end.
```

---

```
unit uObjects;

interface

uses
  Vcl.StdCtrls,
  System.Classes,
  uStorageInterface,
  Spring.Container,
  Spring.Services,
  Spring.Container.Common;

type

  TMyButton= class (TButton, IStorageObject)
  private
    FStorage: IStorageService;
    function GetStorage: IStorageService;

  protected
    procedure DoExit; override;

  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;

implementation

{ TMyButton }
constructor TMyButton.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  FStorage:= ServiceLocator.GetService<IStorageService>;
end;

procedure TMyButton.DoExit;
begin
  inherited;
    if assigned(FStorage) then
  begin
    self.Caption:= FStorage.Path;
  end;
end;

function TMyButton.GetStorage: IStorageService;
begin
  Result:= FStorage;
end;

end.
```

---

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes,
  Vcl.Dialogs;

type
  TDataModule2 = class(TDataModule)
    procedure DataModuleCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  DataModule2: TDataModule2;

implementation

uses
  uStorage,
  uObjects,
  uStorageInterface,
  Spring.Services,
  Spring.Container;

{%CLASSGROUP 'Vcl.Controls.TControl'}

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TDataModule2.DataModuleCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  GlobalContainer.RegisterType<TStorageService>.Implements<IStorageService>.DelegateTo(
    function: TStorageService
    begin
      Result := TStorageService.Create();
      Result.Path:= 'MyButton';
    end).AsSingleton;
  GlobalContainer.Build;
end;
end.
```

In the constructor TMyButton.Create(AOwner: TComponent) I want to replace ServiceLocator with a field injection but I can't find how to do this.

Some example but it doesn't work. I can't see the problem.

```
unit uObjects;

interface

uses
  Vcl.StdCtrls,
  System.Classes,
  uStorageInterface,
  Spring.Container,
  Spring.Services,
  Spring.Container.Common;

type

  TMyButton= class (TButton, IStorageObject)
  private
    [Inject]
    FStorage: IStorageService;
    function GetStorage: IStorageService;

  protected
    procedure DoExit; override;

  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;

implementation

{ TMyButton }
constructor TMyButton.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  //FStorage:= ServiceLocator.GetService<IStorageService>;
end;

procedure TMyButton.DoExit;
begin
  inherited;
    if assigned(FStorage) then
  begin
    self.Caption:= FStorage.Path;
  end;
end;

function TMyButton.GetStorage: IStorageService;
begin
  Result:= FStorage;
end;

end.
```

---

```
procedure TDataModule2.DataModuleCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  GlobalContainer.RegisterType<TStorageService>.Implements<IStorageService>.DelegateTo(
    function: TStorageService
    begin
      Result := TStorageService.Create();
      Result.Path:= 'MyButton';
    end).AsSingleton;

  GlobalContainer.RegisterType<TMyButton>.Implements<IStorageObject>.InjectField('FStorage');
  GlobalContainer.Build;
end;
```

When I create A TMyButton at run time, the FStorage in TMyButton is nill.
When I use FStorage:= ServiceLocator.GetService; in the constructor then the FStorage is assigned. But I want to use the injection and not the ServiceLocator. If this is possible.

Comment: FStorage is nil when I use the inject attribute

Answer (score 1):

First The registratioin of `TMyButton` is wrong. The container will not fill in nil for AOwner by itself. That means it will fall back to the TObject constructor leaving the button instance half initialized.

Either use a subdependency resolver to do that for TComponent ctors or explicitly register it that way.

```
GlobalContainer.RegisterType<TMyButton>.Implements<IStorageObject>
  .DelegateTo(
    function: TMyButton
    begin
      Result := TMyButton.Create(nil);
    end)
  .InjectField('FStorage');
```

Now attention! If you are resolving this as TMyButton somewhere the container does not know how to resolve that because you specified IStorageObject as service type. If you specify a service type the container does not resolve the class unless explicitly defined.
However there is a small glitch here as the container tries to register that class again whenever it is being resolved. That results in a second registration for TMyButton which does not have the field injection specified. I will fix that.

Until then you can fix this by adding an `Implements<TMyButton>` to your registration.

Comment: I know that the registration is wrong. Is there a link about subdependency. I'm just a beginner and is sometimes difficult to understand this methode.